# How to scan Entities from a JAR? ERROR: Not a managed type:

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jar

I have create a JAR with 2 Entities:

**CAR CLASS**

```
package com.jdm.legends.common.dto;

import com.jdm.legends.common.enums.CarColor;
import com.jdm.legends.common.enums.CarCompany;
import com.jdm.legends.common.enums.CarFuelType;
import com.jdm.legends.common.enums.CarTransmissionType;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

import lombok.*;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static jakarta.persistence.CascadeType.ALL;
import static jakarta.persistence.EnumType.STRING;
import static jakarta.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

@Entity(name = "cars")
@Table
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String carName;

    @Enumerated(STRING)
    private CarColor carColor;

    @Enumerated(STRING)
    private CarTransmissionType carTransmissionType;

    @Enumerated(STRING)
    private CarCompany carCompany;

    @Enumerated(STRING)
    private CarFuelType carFuelType;

    private int km;

    private int productionYear;

    private BigDecimal initialPrice;

    private int hp;

    private boolean damaged;

    private int quantityInStock;

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "car")
    private List<HistoryBid> historyBidList = new ArrayList<>();

    private LocalDateTime startDateCarPostedOnline;
    private LocalDateTime deadlineCarToSell;
}
```

I want to use this class inside another micro-service:

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT hb.id AS id, hb.bid_value AS bidValue FROM history_bid hb INNER JOIN cars c on hb.car_id = c.id " +
            "WHERE c.id = :id ORDER BY hb.bid_value DESC LIMIT 7;", nativeQuery = true)
    List<HistoryBidInterface> getBiggestHistoryBidByCarID(Long id);
}
```

For this micro-service, I put in pom.xml the following:

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jdm.legends.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdm-legends-commons</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

.
In order to recognize the class with its properties.

When I want to start the micro-service, it says: *Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.jdm.legends.common.dto.Car
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]*

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI0La.png)

I have tries @EntityScan, @ComponentScan and nothing seems to work.

**MAIN METHOD IN THE MICRO-SERVICE**

[MAain.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8OTJ.png)

How can I get over this error?

If you need extra information, let me know.

I tries the following annotations: @EntityScan, @ComponentScan and nothing seems to work.
[structure packages JAR and micro-service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCurU.png)

Comment: are your entities under dto package ? if yes in your entityScan add dto

Comment: Yes, there are. I have tried, and same output ... error

Comment: Your Hibernate 5.6.10 is too old for Jakarta JPA used in the entity class. Consider updating your spring-boot-starter-parent to the newest one.

Comment: @Mar-Z , I have upgrade to  <version>2.7.12</version> and same error happens with hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final

Comment: Didn't I tell you to the newest? The newest version is Spring Boot 3.1.1 with Hibernate 6.2.5 I'm pretty sure your external project uses Spring Boot 3+ and Hibernate 6+

Comment: Of course you will also need to migrate your code properly. Like renaming imports javax.persistence to jakarta.persistence etc. Check here for details https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#_jakarta_persistence